# How do I track transactions made from my stolen phone

Tags: coinbase.com

My phone was stolen few days ago, and the thief has transferred funds from my coinbase app to this account.

"1MaFK75o7iayPHEdjPJnD7ofaG13gAZcxP"
on 1st Jan at 14.40 (CET or Stockholm time)

I need to find the owner of this account number as he is the thief who has stolen my phone and money.

Comment: I believe there are some special services for exactly this. I've only heard of them, never used them. However, I'd come to terms with the high likelihood you'll never catch him, unless he's an associate.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for your phone and your bitcoins, but unfortunately you can't find someone thanks to a wallet address. Wallet addresses are pseudonymous and any kind of personnal information (like IP address) are not stored on the blockchain.